# FreePascal adding elements on binaryTree

Tags: binary-tree, pascal, freepascal

So im trying to add all 'spent' data, belonging to specific client number, on a binary tree.

```
Type

pointer_tree = ^bTree;    
bTree = record
     nclient: integer;
     spent: integer;
     big, small: pointer_tree
end;

{adder is 0}
function add (pT: pointer_tree; client_number: integer; adder: integer): integer;
begin
     if pT <> nil then begin
        if pT^.nclient = client_number then
           adder:= pT^.spent + adder
        add(pT^.big,client_number,adder);
        add(pT^.small,client_number,adder);
     end;
     add:= adder;
end;
```

Function add will not return the added elements and will return a random number instead. Also is there a better way to add them all up?

Comment: `add` returns a integer and will not return a list of elements! Is this a problem? What would you expect?

Comment: im expecting a integer not a list of elements, I want to add them all up

Comment: When you pass `adder` as an argument to `add` you then need to add what `add` returned to your local result.

Comment: do you mean the last line in add? add:= adder + add (?)

Comment: I mean when you call `add` for `big` and `small`. As it stands, the results from these two `add` calls are thrown away. The `adder` you pass in becomes a local copy in the called function.

Comment: you're right, now I get it thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the way that you're using the variable 'adder' as both a parameter to the function and also as a temporary store for the calculated value. I think it would be better if the function were written as follows, without the 'adder' variable:

```
function add (pT: pointer_tree; client_number: integer): integer;
begin
 result:= 0;
 if pT <> nil then 
  begin
   if pT^.nclient = client_number then result:= pT^.spent;
   inc (result, add (pT^.big, client_number));
   inc (result, add (pT^.small, client_number));
  end;
end;
```

Incidentally, your code is missing a semicolon after the 'adder:= pT^.spent + adder' line.